# "Unknown" attachement on outlook.office.com

Tags: microsoft-outlook, microsoft-outlook-365

The issue: A user on a Samsung mobile phone receives a photo via text message. They click "share via email" and send it from their personal email address to two different addresses:

Their work address recently migrated to outlook.office.com.
A Gmail address.
The attachment is received with the name "Unknown" (without extension) on both accounts.

Both outlook.office.com and Gmail accounts are configured via IMAP on Outlook 365. The Gmail account can see the image, but the outlook.office.com account cannot.

Note that the work email address was previously hosted by SFR Business, which provides an Outlook-like solution. The issue did not arise at that time.

In summary, it is likely that this is a setting on the outlook.office.com platform, but it is not immediately clear what the issue may be.

Comment: What you have not said is whether the original text message is legitimate. This just screams malware - but I could be wrong.

Comment: The message is legitimate. It's a test that I'm sending with just a photo.

Answer (score 0):

The issue is likely due to being sent without extension. It should be sent with file type indicated, e.g., "Unknown **.jpg**".

Test that by *saving* the file from Outlook and adding extension to the saved file; it should then be viewable.

You can also try opening the Outlook email in another mail reader, such as Thunderbird, to see if Outlook itself is the cause of the issue.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback.

Adding the extension works but it's a bit complicated for this kind of user.
Outlook shouldn't be the cause of the problem since the same Outlook accesses the Gmail account via IMAP and correctly displays the attachment.